Make external device -> internal storage appear as a drive with letter. Deleted file recovery from Garmin Watch
General problem:
I want to restore deleted file from Garmin Watch.
I have Garmin Epix Pro Gen 2. Activity file seems to be deleted by the software itself. It was there fully functional, just not synced to online server. Then gone after a day.
I have tried to use file recovery software like EasyUS, AnyRecovery, Stellar. Seems like it can recover files only from devices that appear like a drive in Windows - with assigned letter.
Garmin Watch appear as an 'External device' with 'Internal Storage'. I assume that's why it's not discoverable by the software.
The path to the device "This PC\EPIX PRO - 47mm\Internal Storage\GARMIN"
I would like to make it as "[drive letter]\GARMIN"
Is it possible? Is there a better way to restore deleted file from external device?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
